# Is Apple Keyring data stored locally-only on devices?

Tags: keychain

I would like to understand if the keyring database is stored only on the local Apple device or if it is also stored on servers on the internet.

Comment: It depends whether you have iCloud Keychain synchronisation enabled or disabled.

Comment: @MikeScott Please consider posting an answer clarifying the statement.  Any supporting links would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: @gatorback do you mean "keyring" or "keychain"?

Comment: This seems like something you can look up. I Googled "keychain cloud" and got quite a lot of material on how this works.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike Scott [wrote](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/215182/is-apple-keyring-data-stored-locally-only-on-devices#comment435736_215182), depending on your iCloud backup.

See ["Set up iCloud Keychain"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085).

See "Keychain data protection" on page 20 of the ["iOS Security Guide"](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) for how the keychain works, how it protects access to keychain items so they are only available when the phone is unlocked, using the secure enclave processor.